# Remove output from find command - Shell

Tags: linux, shell, tomcat

I have a shell script that is getting versions of Tomcat installed on my system. I am able to print found versions to `stdout` using the `find` command. However, I am also getting output for directories and files that are not found. How can I remove this from the output and only show found files in output? Code and output is below.

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
  
APP="Apache Tomcat"

# Common install paths to iterate over
set -- "/opt" "/usr/share" "/var" "/var/lib" "/usr" "/usr/local" 

if [ -x "$(command -v unzip)" ]; then
    for _i in "$@"; do
        find_bootstrap=$(find $_i/tomcat*/bin/ -name bootstrap.jar)
        for found in $find_bootstrap; do
            get_version=$(unzip -p $found META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | grep -Eo 'Implementation-Version: [0-9].[0-9]?.[0-9]?[0-9]?' | grep -Eo '[0-9].[0-9]?.[0-9]?[0-9]?')
            echo "$APP $get_version"
        done
    done
fi
```

Output:

```
Apache Tomcat 7.0.82
Apache Tomcat 8.5.30
Apache Tomcat 9.0.31
find: ‘/var/tomcat*/bin/’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/var/lib/tomcat*/bin/’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/usr/tomcat*/bin/’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/usr/local/tomcat*/bin/’: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way that I can get rid of `find: ‘/var/tomcat*/bin/’: No such file or directory` if no file is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` (as most commands) prints errors on **stderr**, so you can separate them from the output using, e.g. a redirection:

```sh
find_bootstrap=$(find $_i/tomcat*/bin/ -name bootstrap.jar 2>/dev/null)
```

**Remark:** To find out all installations of Tomcat I would rather look for `catalina.jar` (less chances for a name conflict) which would give:

```sh
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' jar; do
    version=$(unzip -p "$jar" META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | grep -oP '(?<=Implementation-Version: )\d+.\d+.\d+');
    echo Apache Tomcat $version
done < <(find /usr /var /opt -name 'catalina.jar' -print0 2>/dev/null)
```